# Storing time from input field

Tags: visualforce, datetime, inputfield

I am working on a form that has to contain a time input, maybe something like this figure.

[image]

The problem is that there's no data type such as time, and I tried to use bootstrap timepicker but it doesn't work, so what sould I do to take time and save it ?

Comment: While not an immediate solution, this idea could always use more votes: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrUVAA0

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery to make it simple.

$('#basicExample').timepicker();

Then pass the variable using an action funtion

Samples:
http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

good luck!